# Cumulocity Tools - Deploy application as zip via Tools

Tags: cumulocity

is it possible to deploy an application as zip file via the cumulocity tools? If so, can someone show an example. I've seen that there is an option -p, --packagePath, but I don't know how to use it.

Our goal is to use Jenkins to automatically update an applications. The zip file should always have the current version number of the application in its name.

Thank you,
Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deploy an application with cumulocity tools you need the following command:

```
c8y deploy:app
```

but you need, like you already mentioned, an additional option (-p) that specifies the path to the .zip file that you want to deploy.

In general the c8y build:app  command will build the application and saves it to the build folder. In this case, your deploy command should look like this:

```
c8y deploy:app -p ./build/<nameOfBuild>.zip
```

Kind regards